# How to search repository for commits with specific commit message

Tags: git, version-control

I'm trying to get all commits in my Git-Repository which commit messages contain a specific text.

Is there a feature in Git which can get me the commits? Is it possible to get what I want in another way so I could write a short script that displays the commit-ids?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Might help you.. Not painful believe me XD
https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=preg+in+git&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=preg+expressions++in+git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `git log --grep="specific text"` to find the regular expression in commit messages.

If you want to get only the list of SHAs, you have to add the `--pretty=format:%h` switch which will print the 7 character long SHA of the commits, or use `%H` instead of `%h` to print the full SHA.